# removeEventListener not working?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

It's been asked several times before, but all the one's I've seen and tried either aren't it, or don't seem to work for some reason

onEnter takes a callback that it will fire whenever the enter key is pressed (that much works), but when I try calling `removeEventListener()`, it doesn't seem to work. I've tried making the function a variable instead of a declaration, I've tried setting the `useCapture` flags for both adding/removing, and I've tried all combinations of trying to `.bind(this)` to either the function arguments or the function itself, and also putting the `removeEventListener()` line in different places (before/after the `setTimeout()`), but to no avail. The event listeners either persist (and accumulate on the `div`) or don't seem to get added at all in some tries

```
MyConsole.prototype.onEnter = function(callback) {
    const callCallback = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && typeof callback === "function") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                callback();
            }.bind(this), 0);
            this.textAreaInputDiv.removeEventListener("keyup", callCallback.bind(this), true);
        }
    }
    this.textAreaInputDiv.addEventListener("keyup", callCallback.bind(this), true);
}
```

Any help would be hella appreciated

Comment: How come you so many listeners for keyevent? Use one eventListener for one event and delegate it on anything in the DOM you want multiple times. Attaching to document works good for keyCode13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass exactly the same function to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

```
MyConsole.prototype.onEnter = function(callback) {
    const callCallback = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && typeof callback === "function") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                callback();
            }.bind(this), 0);
            this.textAreaInputDiv.removeEventListener("keyup", callCallbackBound, true);
        }
    };

    const callCallbackBound = callCallback.bind(this);

    this.textAreaInputDiv.addEventListener("keyup", callCallbackBound, true);
};
```

In fact an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) would be a better option here since [it does not have its own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

And you probably meant `callback.bind(this)` in the `setTimeout` so I let myself to fix that as well:

```
MyConsole.prototype.onEnter = function(callback) {
    const callCallback = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && typeof callback === "function") {
            setTimeout(callback.bind(this), 0);
            this.textAreaInputDiv.removeEventListener("keyup", callCallback, true);
        }
    };

    this.textAreaInputDiv.addEventListener("keyup", callCallback, true);
};
```